# how to use delimiter in the script to avoid numerical and special characters

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

Is there any logic to write a shell script to go back up into the previous directory which has "n" number of files like abc-1.0.1-xy.rpm, xyz-3.2.1-bc.rpm, a-bd-2.3.1-ty.rpm etc.. with same pattern.

I need the first name of it before the numeric starts(which can acts as a delimiter) i.e(-(0-9)) can be the delimiter. the output should be abc, xfz, a-bd, etc.

```
for p in *.rpm; do echo "${p%-*}"; done
```

I made a try with this command, but it stops and output as xyz-3.2.1. but I need xyz only.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

If you need the package name of a rpm, use:

```
rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME}\n' *.rpm  2>/dev/null
```